# Get content from WordPress to php

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to get information from WP for a while now and I still can't get it to work. What I'm trying to do is to get the information from an online resume and display it on the site.

The problem is that I haven't worked with WP a lot before and I can't figure out if there is a better way than SQL extraction to get that information.

This is the code I have now, it's very simple but doesn't work.

```
$output = '

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
    <h1 class="title">'.the_custom_field('_candidate_name', 144).'</h1>
    <ul class="contactInformation">
        <li id="fullName">//This is where the name should go</li>
        <li id="adress">//I want to fetch the adress and echo it here etc.</li>
        <li id="phoneNumber"></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="resumePicture">
        <img src="mVqghXM.jpg" height="auto" width="100px">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="education">
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>

<div id="experience">

</div>


</body>
</html>';
```

I've tried using get_custom_field as well as get_resume_field and placing them into a variable but i get an error that says it's undefined, and I presume that is because I don't have the WP Job Manager Field Editor plugin.

I would rather find another way to do this, either via some other WP compatible function or via SQL, instead of having to buy that plugin.

I would also love one of you to explain to me briefly how the WP system/database is built, because that would help immensely.

Thank you!

EDIT: I found the way of fetching the data from the database. It was get_resume_field, but what I'd done was copy the meta_key straight off the database, being "_candidate_name", but when I took the first underscore away, it worked. Thank you both for helping with the two problems I had. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use three files in your custom php file to get and use all wordpress function. Try this.

```
include_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-config.php");
include_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");
include_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php");
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, the functions now run as they should. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> You have made to collect all the HTML into a single variable as per you need.

The major important thing is that you have to echo/ return the variable to print the output.

This will do the trick if you return it from a function

```
function get_page()
{
   $output = '<p>Welcome</p>';
   $output .= '<p>Again</p>';
   return $output;
}
```

After the return you have to echo the statement by calling the function

```
$test = get_page();
echo $test;
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome

Again
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue of getting the echo to work, **but**, the other problem I'm having is that I cannot fetch the information from the database as I want to. Do you know of any good way of doing this, preferably integrated into WP?

Comment: Have you made the wp-config file to connect with this page . If not pls connect it and then alone the wp_queries will work

Comment: Including the **wp-config.php** is required to make the datas fetch from Wordpress database. Orelse it will never fetch at all

Comment: Let me know if you face any hindrance in development.

Comment: It does not fetch the data that I want, but I no longer have any errors when executing the code.

Comment: Can you post the code what you have done in the question by editing it. I will rectify your Error. :)